# Useable Groovy files links in eclipse's stacktrace views

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I'm running Groovy code inside a Java app. In Eclipse, stacktraces show the related groovy files and lines. They are clickable, but it shows a *"Source not found for com.mycomp.MyGroovyClass"* message.

It is not able to find the file, although the **find ressource** works for `MyGroovyClass.groovy`.

My question : **It there a way to make Eclipse open the wanted groovy file ?**

Extract from StackTrace. The `MyGroovyClass.groovy:49` is clickable, but show the above message :

```
at com.mycomp.MyGroovyClass(MyGroovyClass.groovy:49)
```

*RQ: I currently use Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), with the Groovy-Eclipse plugin (2.9.1.xx-201411061335-e44-RELEASE)*

Comment: is the source file MyGroovyClass.groovy in a source folder under com/mycomp/ ?

Comment: @blackdrag indeed, it is in a different resource folder, which suits better the source organization(taking advantage of Groovy's tolerance on folder<->package). I will check tomorrow if it changes anything

Comment: yes, please check. Groovy might be more tolerant here, but to find resources in eclipse you depend on eclipse and jdt, which have only Java in mind, so you have to stick to Java conventionsfor these things

Comment: @blackdrag, in fact the .groovy files just have to be in a source folder (and no need to have a folder/file<->package/classname correspondance :-) ).

It was not the case in my project, as the groovy files are compiled and loaded in a different ClassLoader. Note that now Type lookup also works, which is quite convenient. Thanks a lot. If you convert this info to answer, I'll be happy to accept it